# Persistent Web Server Connection from Multiple Hosts

Tags: web-server

Suppose that a Web server runs in Host C on port 8080. Suppose this Web server uses persistent connections, and is currently receiving requests from two different   Hosts, A and B. Are all of the requests being sent through the same socket at Host C? If they are being passed through different sockets, do both of the sockets have port 8080?

**I would think: they are being passed through the same socket on the same port(:8080) since this webserver uses a *persistent* connection? I.e. Since this connection is persistent, it doesnt give a new connection to each incoming host or connection** Is this true? Why?

Comment: This sounds like homework to me. Homework questions are not on-topic here.

Comment: That's a big assumption. Nonetheless, it will help further site goers, so care to provide some helpful answer here?

Comment: @Adrian There has been discussion [on Meta](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/1265/user-seems-to-ask-only-homework-questions-is-this-a-problem-or-should-i-just-i), but I'm not sure homework questions are off-topic.  Regardless, this user's questions thus far do read as copy/paste from a textbook.

Answer (score 2):

Applications that persistently listen on a port handle connection-management of the higher level protocol. The two separate connections over the same port will be handled by the same instance of an application. Two connections, one application, one listening socket. The application is responsible for maintaining application connection state, and managing the TCP connection events (open/close) for the Operating system.

New connections are established at the operating system layer, and once established are passed on to the application listening on that port. When a connection is closed, it can be closed by the OS (generally, unexpected termination for some reason) or the application (normal shutdown), and the application has to handle all cases.

Comment: Can this: `Two connections, one application, one listening socket` ALSO be true for N Connections, one application, one listening socket?